# Decimal comparison failing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to compare the following scenarios using decimal comparison in jquery.

```
var a=99999999999.99;
var b=9999999999999999999

if(parseFloat(a).toFixed(2) > parseFloat(b).toFixed(2))
```

This always returns `true`. How to fix the Issue?

Some of the outputs from what I tried:

```
parseFloat(9874563212).toFixed(2) > parseFloat(98745632).toFixed(2) true
parseFloat(98745632).toFixed(2) > parseFloat(987456321).toFixed(2) false
parseFloat(99999999999.99).toFixed(2) > parseFloat(9999999999999999999).toFixed(2) true
parseFloat(99999999999.99).toFixed(2) > parseFloat(999999999999).toFixed(2) false
parseFloat(99999999999.99).toFixed(2) > parseFloat(9999999999999).toFixed(2) false
parseFloat(99999999999.99).toFixed(2) > parseFloat(99999999999999).toFixed(2) false
parseFloat(99999999999.99).toFixed(2) > parseFloat(999999999999999).toFixed(2) false
parseFloat(99999999999.99).toFixed(2) > parseFloat(9999999999999999).toFixed(2) true
parseFloat(99999999999.99).toFixed(2) > parseFloat(1111111111111111).toFixed(2) true
parseFloat(99999999999.99).toFixed(2) > parseFloat(111111111111111).toFixed(2) true
```

Comment: Doesn't `toFixed()` return a string?

Comment: You don't need the `parseFloat`. `toFixed` is a property of the `Number` object so both integers and floating point numbers have it

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You are comparing strings, not numbers (`.toFixed()` returns a string). Try:

```
if (parseFloat(parseFloat(a).toFixed(2)) > parseFloat(parseFloat(b).toFixed(2)))
```

Or, if `a` and `b` are already numbers, as in your example

```
if (parseFloat(a.toFixed(2)) > parseFloat(b.toFixed(2)))
```

Or better

```
if (Math.round(a * 100) > Math.round(b * 100))
```

Comment: Or `Math.round(a*100)/100` if you want the original float back (not necessary if you only want to compare)

Comment: @dtech I've elided it because it was theoretically influential, because he was only comparing them.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative solution is to reduce a number from the other and check its absolute value is lower than a threshold value.

```
const threshold = 0.001
if(Math.abs(a-b) > threshold) {
  // not matching
} else {
  // match
}
```