# Why does my JS "if" statement always evaluate to false?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, comparison-operators

My code:

```
if (calculatedColumn5 >= calculatedColumn) {
'Enough credits.'
}
{
'Not enough credits.'
}
```

Evaluates to 'Not enough credits' even when 'calculatedColumn5' is clearly greater than 'calculatedColumn'.

I even tried this:

```
if (calculatedColumn5 >= calculatedColumn) {
'Enough credits.'
}
else if (calculatedColumn5 < calculatedColumn)
{
'Not enough credits.'
}
else {
''
}
```

...and it always evaluates to ''! So is there a problem with my "if" conditions where they simply always evaluate to false?

The variables by the way (calculatedColumn5 and calculatedColumn) are both decimal values.

Comment: Well, what are your values for `calculatedColumn5` and `calculatedColumn` and how do you get them?

Comment: Note that your first code snippet is missing an "else" making the second block unconditional.

Comment: What is the type of `calculatedColumn5` and `calculatedColumn` Be sure that they are either int or float, not strings, else use `parseFloat` on each of them? Also, 'enough credits' is not valid in javascript. you should rather `alert('enough credits');` or `console.log('enough credits');`. Moreover, missing an "else" in the very first code.

Comment: @briosheje It is valid Javascript to use an expression as a statement (that's how 'use strict' works).  It just doesn't do anything.

Comment: SO is not a debugger. You should run your code in an debugging environment like firebug or chromes internal stuff before asking here. If you do, make sure to supply all the stuff people might need. In your case, the origin of the values.

Comment: @error: then how does he know that `..and it always evaluates to ''!`? (OP words :P)

Comment: @briosheje It doesn't do what OP wants it to do, but I was only disagreeing with your assertion that it "is not valid in javascript."

Comment: @error: well, true (and thanks, didn't know that), I'm still not sure how he got that that echo though :P

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the values are in fact strings and are being compared as strings.

Try using:

```
if (parseFloat(calculatedColumn5) >= parseFloat(calculatedColumn)) {
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I also tried changing the calculated fields to value.parseFloat, which is perhaps not correct verbiage but it evaluated to null.

Comment: Anyway, if (parseFloat(calculatedColumn5) >= parseFloat(calculatedColumn)) {
'Enough credits.'
}
{
'Not enough credits.'
} - that still always evaluates to 'Not enough credits.'

Comment: You forgot the word else as "error" mentioned. Also what are you doing with those strings, u might want console.log('Enough credits');

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that in JS an undefined (not initialized) variable evaluates to false. Try the following:

```
var a;
if (a) console.log('True'); else console.log('False');
```

**Evaluates to false.**

The same is true for any logic operation performed on undefined values.

```
var a;
var b = 5;
if (a > b) console.log('greater'); else console.log('lower or equal');
```

**Evaluates to false.**

Comment: I believe that the properties are defined properly (though maybe there's an issue with their data types?). I'm writing scripted columns in Intrinsik Informer - other calculated columns can be used in formulas with no problem.

Comment: if you debug and all the operands have values... then I did not tackle your issue :-)

Answer (score -1):

You should round both or at least get rid of the decimal to avoid unwanted behavior. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18741293/2192152

Also:

```
// Test if ===, or greated
if (calculatedColumn5 >= calculatedColumn) {
'Enough credits.'
}
// Test if strictly inferior
else if (calculatedColumn5 < calculatedColumn)
{
'Not enough credits.'
}
// this will NEVER fire as all other cases have been tested.
else {
''
}
```

Edit:
this is working. assuming 2 decimal, but you can multiply by 100,1000 or whatever you need. (you could even do it automatically by splitting the `a` variable and determining the length behind the period).

```
var a = 12.21;
var b = 12.35;
a = Math.round(a * 100);
b = Math.round(b * 100);

var test = a > b ? 'A > B' : 'A < B';

alert(test);
```

Comment: Still digesting everyone's comments - but how can I round or get rid of the decimal, when some students have half credits? Let me try if (parseInt(2*calculatedColumn5) >= parseInt(2*calculatedColumn)) {
'Enough credits.'
}
else
{
'Not enough credits.'
}...

Comment: That code has the same problem; it seems to always evaluate to false.

Comment: You can't just truncate the numbers and assume it will work. The decimal portions of the numbers is fairly important here.

Comment: @ssube correct, but we lack some information here. Best solution, given the data, would be for me to determinate how many number are behind the decimal, (X), then do a number = number* (10 * X ). Then simply compare them. A bit ugly but well..