# Decimal Comparison without rounding in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 textboxex for decimal values and I need to compare them in JavaScript. The scenario is

```
var first = $('#txtFirst').val();
var second= $('#txtSecond').val();
```

In textboxex I'm entering following values

- first => 99999999999998.999999997
- second => 99999999999998.999999991

I tried the below code

```
     if (parseFloat(parseFloat(first).toFixed(10)) <= parseFloat(parseFloat(second).toFixed(10)))
```

This returns true because it rounds it so both the values becomes 99999999999999. How to fix it?

Comment: Please check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741177/decimal-comparison-failing-in-javascript)

Comment: You can round up to the number of point than compare both

Comment: why can't you compare the 2 strings `first` and `second`?

Comment: @Alexis yes, I just want to compare without rounding.

Comment: Like @gurvinder372 said. You can compare strings, it works

Comment: @gurvinder372 No, I cant compare two string because if I enter First => 45 and second => 446. It gets fail. It returns False.

Comment: So 45 is equal to 446?

Comment: @KevDev In this case both a and b are simply number they are not in " " (double codes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compare without converting into integer

```
var first = $('#txtFirst').val();
var second= $('#txtSecond').val();

if ( first == second )
{
  // they are equal
}
```

if you want to compare upto 10 decimals then

```
var first10Decimals  = first.split(".").pop().substring(0,10);
var second10Decimals  = second.split(".").pop().substring(0,10);
if ( first10Decimals  == second10Decimals )
{
   //they are equal
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla JavaScript can't handle such big numbers. You should use something like big.js that is designed to work with arbitrary large numbers :

- GitHub : https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/
- Documentation : https://mikemcl.github.io/big.js/